# How to sort the types of materials from one column

Tags: google-sheets

I have in Sheet1, column B, 5 types of materials. In column L, I have numbered the position of each one.
So, Position 1 to 6, is 'Plastic tube':

[image]

I need a formula, in Sheet2, that can calculate this automatically, so for each type of material to show in what position can be found.

Like this:

[image]

or

[image]

It would be better if can be search by position, because the types of material can be one, 2, or more.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CDdvFChCx2_1bZ3rY2ZApQOjOM22rTcLx4mUllNqYqw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the difference between `Plastic tube` in `1,2,3,4,5,6` and `Plastic tube` in `15,16,17`?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: 'What is the difference between Plastic tube in 1,2,3,4,5,6 and Plastic tube in 15,16,17" - there is no difference. Just to show what kind of material is in each position. I tried with IFERROR but not working as I want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(TOCOL(B2:B, 1)), LAMBDA(r, 
   {r, JOIN(", ", FILTER(L2:L, B2:B=r))}))
```

FILTER `L2:L` for rows that match each unique article in `B2:B`.

Join the resulting arrays delimited by a comma and space `", "` and prepend a column with the unique article that was matched.